# Angular with select list not populating the viewModel

Tags: angularjs

I'm returning data from the api that looks like this:

```
[
   {
      createDate:'somedate',
      updateDate:'someOtherDate',
      id: 'abx123ef2D-00-4d256d', //this is a Guid
      name: 'stateName'
   },
   {
      createDate:'somedate',
      updateDate:'someOtherDate',
      id: 'a different Guid here', //this is a Guid
      name: 'stateName'
   }
]
```

here is my select list:

```
            <select id="State"
                    ng-model="viewmodel.newRegion.stateId"
                    class="form-control"
                    ng-options="state.id as state.name for state in viewModel.states">
                <option value="">Select State</option>
            </select>
```

but when i go to run the submit I do not have any newRegion.id.

can anyone help?

Comment: The select is bound to `viewmodel.newRegion.stateId`. So it's not surprising that you have nothing in `newRegion.id`. You could have other bugs, so post your code.

Comment: Voting to close for typo.

Comment: okay, what does that mean? do you want me to delete question?